# Generating a checksum or hash for field values of a record

Tags: php, mysql, hash, checksum

I want to have a column containing a hash or checksum as a single value to compare records. Is it possible to do something like this in pure SQL ? Do you see this as practical versus a programmatic solution in PHP ?

Comment: MySQL has hash functions, so it is possible. But, as already commented, it is important to know what your hash is meant to be used for ? Depending on the use case consider whether having the code in the application makes more sense that putting it in the DB.

Comment: This is for the purposes of integrity or synchronizing (programmatic).

Comment: @OllieJones To reach 100% :) ? Will have a look through older questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  `MD5()`, `SHA1()`, and `SHA2()` are all workable hash functions.

You must compute the values of these functions row by row and query by query. For example, every time you insert a row you'll have to insert the hash value, doing something like this:

```
INSERT INTO x
       name=?name,
       address=?address,
       hash=MD5(CONCAT(?name,?address))
```

You'll need to do something similar on each update.  If you get it wrong, which is remarkably easy especially if your table structure changes, your hashes become worse than useless.

By the way, MD5 isn't cryptographically secure for authentication any more. However, it's still an acceptable choice for this kind of hashing in a closed system.

Comment: You could use a trigger to do it for you... but I can't help wonder what the point would be: the hash will always be that of the underlying data (unless the database has been corrupted, but there are other measures in place to detect/handle that).  So what value does it add?

Comment: @eggyal If synchronizing a local and distant table programatically it provides a single value to work with or perhaps a key if read only as PKs wouldn't correspond if on autoincrement. A date field could be used depending on requirements but the question of integrity also interests me.

Comment: @JamesPoulson: Why not use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html)/[clustering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-cluster.html) to perform synchronisation for you?  It's a difficult thing to do correctly, with plenty of edge-cases.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @eggyal I understand. I should have mentionned that the distant database is on mutual web hosting, port 3306 often being closed.  To give context, someone rightly mentionned that centralizing application access online is an interesting idea but it's not much use if the internet connection goes south. So I'm having a good think of how to make an offline solution to take the relay.